# Div appears small on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, size

I have a website, can see it here:
http://synodins.com/icemaps.

It works well in most browser etc, the problem arises on mobile. Then the introduction box becomes very small, and needs to be zoomed in to become normal again. Once people have done that all is well and like in any desktop/laptop.

But people don't want to do this initial zooming and it also gives a bad first impression.

I have tried programmatically zooming in, but that makes the jquery autocomplete and calendar become incorrectly positioned.

What would be the best way to make the introduction box appear correctly sized on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You can set 2 delegate css files one for mobile and one based for mobile (normally set by screen size and media). Have this for each screen size:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" />
```

Or whichever size you need. So make the div bigger for smaller browser size or change the font size?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use media queries

You set when to apply the css statement

```
@media and screen and (max-width:400px){
    div{
        width:100%;
    }
}
@media and screen and (min-width:400px) and (max-width:1024px){
    div{
        width:80%;
    }
}
@media and screen and (min-width:1024px){
    div{
        width:60%;
    }
}
```

In this way by setting the display dimensions you can set the aspect of elements related to that dimension.